# How to find the latest timestamped data (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, timestamp, vlookup

I have time stamped data up to the minute that I would like to find latest daily version.

Example:

```
   TimeStamp
1/01/2015 9:26
1/01/2015 21:47
2/01/2015 9:20
2/01/2015 21:22
3/01/2015 9:04
3/01/2015 21:01
4/01/2015 8:17
4/01/2015 18:18
5/01/2015 12:02
5/01/2015 20:51
6/01/2015 12:27
6/01/2015 21:15
7/01/2015 9:58
7/01/2015 15:12
7/01/2015 21:25
8/01/2015 10:17
8/01/2015 21:23
```

The TimeStamp column includes the minutes as well. In the next column over, how would you ensure that the latest DAILY value shows up?

For example, the column next to "1/01/2015 9:26" would be blank (or false?) but the column next to "1/01/2015 21:47" would be "1" as it is the latest data from that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$18/(INT($A$2:$A$18)=INT(A2)),1),1,0)
```

This formula does not care if the data is sorted or not, but if the data will always be sorted in Ascending order then a simpler formula will do it:

```
=IF(INT(A2)<>INT(A3),1,0)
```

This will put a 1 in Column B each time the day changes.

[image]